# Granting access of specific user to specific (multiple) docs

Tags: database, database-design, view

I'm building a small project with database. I have a user table which has two columns, `user_id` and `name`, The second table stores the id and name of some documents: it also has two columns  `doc_id` and `doc_name`. **I want to grant access of specific user to specific (multiple) docs.**

For example:

`user1` can access `doc_2` and `doc_3` Only.

`user2` can access `doc_1` and `doc_2` Only and so on.

Users and forms keep changing (eg. after some time i need to add a new doc, and add access to existing or new user to that new doc).

Do i need to change database design? (for example add a column in docs to store name of each user who can access it? ) If this is so, can you tell me what changes i should do?

OR

Is it possible to do by creating views? In this case, do i still need to change the database design? If this is the case, can you tell me an example view please? In this case, will i need to create view for each user? For example if there are 100 users, i will need to create 100 views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third table (I'll call it `user_doc`). You need 2 main columns; `user_id` and `doc_id`.

You then insert one row for each document and user combo that has access permissions.

If their `user_id` doesn't appear in the `user_doc` table with the relvelant `doc_id`, they don't have permission.

A sample query to get a list of all docs a specific user has access to:

```
SELECT doc_id FROM user_doc WHERE user_id = @UserId
```

or to find all users with access to a specific doc:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_doc WHERE doc_id = @DocId
```

Comment: You could use a View to represent users and their permissions, but you'd still need to create that third table and populate it accordingly. Views can only be of use if they have some undelying data to represent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a PERMISSIONS table with relationship between Users & Documents.  The columns could be PERMISSIONS_ID,USER_ID (Refer User), DOC_ID (Refer Document).  Every time access has to be given to a user for a document this table needs to be populated.